# configure test with static lib

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, libz

I am trying to cross compile libpng for RaspberryPi on Ubuntu 14.04 (x_64) with zlib
but configure fails with

> configure:11400: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/home/user/RPI_DEV/lib/include  conftest.c -lz  -lm  >&5
>   /home/user/RPI_DEV/xtools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   configure:11400: $? = 1
>   configure: failed program was:
>   ....

Because I am using toolchain for arm, arm-ld cant find zlib.

Is there any option for configure not to compile with shared lib but to try with static lib (eg. -static -lz).

Command is

> ./configure --enable-static=true --enable-shared=false --with-zlib-include="/home/user/RPI_DEV/lib/include" --with-zlib-lib="/home/user/RPI_DEV/lib/lib"   LDFLGS="-L/home/user/RPI_DEV/lib/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/home/user/RPI_DEV/lib/include"  -enable-static --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/home/user/RPI_DEV/lib --exec-prefix=/home/user/RPI_DEV/lib

Answer (score 1):

You need to cross build *and install* zlib into your toolchain before trying to use it in another project.

What you are doing *might* work but only if you spell LDFLAGS correctly:

LDFLGS="-L/home/user/RPI_DEV/lib/lib"

Note the missing 'A'.  I don't know why your second attempt worked, given you had the same misspelling; possibly you had a correct LDFLAGS in your environment?

Anyway there should be a Ubuntu cross-development guide somewhere that explains how to do this.  It's slightly off topic but for Gentoo you use 'crossdev' to install the toolchain then a crossdev specific version of the normal package installation mechanism ([host]-emerge) to install zlib into the toolchain.

Also, the arguments --with-zlib-include and --with-zlib-lib are not supported by any current version of libpng I can find.  If you are cross-compiling libpng for an RPi (or, indeed, any ARM system) you should be using the latest version of 1.6 that you can find.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone solves this the RIGHT way, this is hack I've done.

1. Open configure.ac file
2. Find and comment out line

> AC_CHECK_LIB(z, zlibVersion, , AC_ERROR([zlib not installed]))

Configure will pass wihout check for zlib and then add zlib by hand

> LDFLGS="-L/home/user/RPI_DEV/lib/lib -L/home/user/RPI_DEV/lib/lib/libz.a"

3. Run autoconf
4. Run ./configure ...